# OnClick and MouseDown not working when using DragMode=dmAutomatic

Tags: delphi

I have a problem with left click on TPanel and TAdvPanel (TMS Components) also. If I set `DragMode = dmAutomatic` then Left click doesn't work. Right click works.

```
procedure TMain_Form.Panel_Item_01MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
if Button = mbLeft then
   begin
     { whatever I type here nothing happen, even showmessage wont popup - no effect}
   end;
if Button = mbRight then
   begin
     { here code works fine }
   end;
end;
```

It seems simple to me but ... can't found the way how to resolve this issue and call procedure on left button click. Guys, any idea?

Comment: When you debug the application, what is the value of the parameter "Button" when you left-click?

Comment: Im not sure how should I check that. No idea :(

Comment: @BotenAnna: Set a breakpoint on the first line of the event handler, and run the program. When you click the panel, the breakpoint is triggered (unless your problem is in fact that the event isn't triggered at all) and you are taken to the debugger, where there are many ways to check the value of a variable.

Comment: Already done. I have set the breakpoint and click on panel. App keep running as nothing happen. Isn't triggered at all.

Comment: Nobody can reproduce your problem. Please supply a complete program that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Strange. Breakpoint is triggered in section :

if Button = mbRight then
   begin
    --> HERE <<--
   end;

but here : 

if Button = mbLeft then
   begin
     --> IMPOSSIBLE <<--
   end;

Comment: You keep saying that. No need to repeat yourself. The problem is not that we cannot understand your problem, rather we cannot reproduce it. We are still waiting for a program that illustrates the problem. As I said, we do not see the behaviour you described.

Comment: Unbeliavable. I guess I found what is problem. When I delete drag&drop code and set TAdvPanel or TPanel : DragMode to ImManual it can run OnClick event. When I turn it on ImAutomatic - no way :) Can you check this out on your computer? Anyone knows what should i do now?

Comment: Are you talking about the `OnClick` event or `MouseDown`? The code you're showing deals with MouseDown; A click is only a click when the mouse button is released, so the VCL can safely handle the mouse down for you... and presumably that's what happens when you set DragMode to automatic.

Comment: Please add this information (about the `DragMode`) to the question itself.

Comment: I confirm the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Guess problem is resolved now.

If you set TPanel component DragMode to dmAutomatic seems it can't trigger the OnClick event. However, when I set same TPanel DragMode to dmManual it can run OnClick even.

Problem solved with little help of OnMouseEnter even where I manually set Panel_Item_01.DragMode := dmManual; Now it can recognize left mouse button and preserve TPanel DragDrop functionality.

Here is complete code :

```
procedure TMain_Form.Panel_Item_01MouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
 if Button = mbLeft then
    begin
     Panel_Item_01.DragMode := dmManual;    
     { ..rest of code.. }  
    end;
 if Button = mbRight then
    begin
     Panel_Item_01.DragMode := dmAutomatic;
     { ..rest of code.. }  
    end;
end;

procedure TMain_Form.Panel_Item_01MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Panel_Item_01.DragMode := dmManual;
end;

procedure TMain_Form.Panel_Item_01MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Panel_Item_01.DragMode := dmAutomatic;
end;
```

Comment: I think it's safe to delete the question. There's little value in it.

Comment: If you say so. No problem with that, you can delete it.

Comment: Well, I cannot. You can though. The answer bears absolutely no relation to the question, which is unanswerable in its current form.

Comment: Changing `DragMode` to `manual` from MouseEnter doesn't make sense: dragging can only start when the mouse is over the surface of the panel, so drag mode would effectively never be `automatic` if you set it to `manual` that way. Might as well keep it "manual" at all times.

Comment: Ahhhh, OK guys. I will delete question anyway even it helps me and resolve this issue. NP as I said. Thanks anyway.

Comment: There *is* some value to this question, but it needs a little editing. For example it needs to make the relation to `DragMode=Auto` clear! The behavior is not intuitive, I'd expect the `OnClick` to fire while in auto-drag mode if I release the mouse button without moving the mouse too much; Yet no mouse event goes through if you set DragMode to automatic!

Comment: Do not delete this, edit it to include all the relevant information. You will not be able to access it again if it's deleted and it might count towards a "quality ban" at some point.

Comment: OK, will left it as it's - can't afford ban at this moment. I'm sure if anyone falls into similar problem it will read and think twice about it. Of course at the end she/he will figure it out. Thanks guys for your help.

Comment: You can't afford a ban and the rest of the SO site can't afford bad question; I only suggested you keep the question because I think there's value in it. Self-deleted questions count because they're selfish, but I'm sure bad questions count even more. Again, my personal opinion, this question is OK.

Comment: @CosminPrund The only risk of ban comes from moderator deletion. If question asker deletes, that is fine.

Comment: @David, I was reading this just yesterday on Meta, self-deletions *are* part of the equation, but they might not be a big part of that. Apparently there are users that self-delete lots of questions, causing others to lose answers. To be clear, I doubt the OP here is in any danger of getting banned.

Answer (score 1):

There is a one trick with this to "check" if the eq. TButton with a DragMode=TDragMode.dmAutomatic.
Simply check the time distance between OnMouseLeave and OnMouseEnter...
The code:

```
uses DateUtils;
var Time1:TDateTime;

procedure TForm4.Button2MouseLeave(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('OnMouseLeave');
  Time1:=Now;
end;

procedure TForm4.Button2MouseEnter(Sender: TObject);
var
  A:Integer;
begin
  A:=MillisecondsBetween(Time1,Now);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('OnMouseEnter '+IntToStr(A));
end;
```

Then see that with clicking the TButton the time distance is always 0. Another events results with a larger time distance.

I know that it's a not clear approach to solve this problem, but Embarcadero sometimes makes me berserk...